# Simple Htaccess Issue

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I have a domain with sitewide https. But i want only one page to be http, because its communicating with some unsecured website. I want all the pages under the `/topic/*` to be redirected. For instance

```
https://example.com/topic/introduction-3/
```

to

```
http://example.com/topic/introduction-3/
```

---

I have tried this code, but it doesn't work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/topic/(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^topic/? http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hello Croises, Thankyou for your quick reply. However this is not working.

Comment: @user1528268 what error are you getting? If it is going in infinite loop, then it means that your application is forcing the URL to stay on https.